# Django savepoint rollback on catching an Integrity Error causes a TransactionManagementError

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, transactions

I am running the following code inside a transaction.atomic block in Django.

```
@transaction.atomic()
def test():
   a.save()
   sid = transaction.savepoint()
   try:
       b.save()
       transaction.savepoint_commit(sid)
   except IntegrityError as e:
       transaction.savepoint_rollback(sid)
   c.save()
```

This code gives me the following Error -

```
TransactionManagementError
An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
```

I followed the following link from the official documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/#s-savepoint-rollback

What am I missing here?

EDIT:-
Adding the stacktrace.

```
    File "/Users/vibhor/Documents/juggernaut/user-venv-new/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/vibhor/Documents/juggernaut/user-venv-new/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 401, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/Users/vibhor/Documents/juggernaut/user-persistence-service/books/models/books.py", line 243, in save
    transaction.savepoint_rollback(sid)
  File "/Users/vibhor/Documents/juggernaut/user-venv-new/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 66, in savepoint_rollback
    get_connection(using).savepoint_rollback(sid)
  File "/Users/vibhor/Documents/juggernaut/user-venv-new/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 328, in savepoint_rollback
    self._savepoint_rollback(sid)
  File "/Users/vibhor/Documents/juggernaut/user-venv-new/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 288, in _savepoint_rollback
    cursor.execute(self.ops.savepoint_rollback_sql(sid))
  File "/Users/vibhor/Documents/juggernaut/user-venv-new/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/vibhor/Documents/juggernaut/user-venv-new/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 59, in execute
    self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
  File "/Users/vibhor/Documents/juggernaut/user-venv-new/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 429, in validate_no_broken_transaction
    "An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't "
TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your post! This way we can see which command caused the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're running into this issue described in the documentation:

> Savepoints may be used to recover from a database error by performing a partial rollback. If you’re doing this inside an `atomic()` block, the entire block will still be rolled back, because it doesn’t know you’ve handled the situation at a lower level! To prevent this, you can control the rollback behavior with the following functions...

As noted there, you probably want to do a `transaction.set_rollback(False)` to prevent the whole atomic block from being rolled back.

Now, is there a reason you're doing this manually? The code you posted could accomplish the same thing with a nested atomic block, and as the documentation notes:

> When the `atomic()` decorator is nested, it creates a savepoint to allow partial commit or rollback. You’re strongly encouraged to use `atomic()` rather than the functions described below.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly) :

> In order to guarantee atomicity, atomic disables some APIs. Attempting to commit, roll back, or change the autocommit state of the database connection within an atomic block will raise an exception.

The proper way of achieving what you want is to create another `atomic` block :

```
@transaction.atomic()
def test():
   a.save()
   try:
       with transaction.atomic():
           b.save()
   except IntegrityError:
       #handle exception here...
       ...
   c.save()
```

Answer (score -2):

```
@transaction.atomic()
def test():
   a.save()
   sid = transaction.savepoint()
   try:
       with transaction.atomic():
           b.save()
           transaction.savepoint_commit(sid)
   except IntegrityError as e:
       transaction.savepoint_rollback(sid)
   c.save()
```

please check this